# Yesterday, I earned the 11 years of service badge and didnt level up

Tags: steam

[image: Here is the proof that this is not BS. I didn't even gain XP.]

I've been on steam since Jan 21 of 2004. I have 112 XP left to reach level 11 (out of a total of 200). With 11 years, I earned 550 XP, which should be enough for both what I have left on level 10, level 11 and 12 (200 XP per level until level 21). I didn't gain any XP AT ALL. I'm still have 112 left to level.

In other words, with this badge, mathematically speaking, I should now be level 13, but what's the problem?

Comment: You should probably re-check some of your numbers; "what I have left on level 1 PLUS level 11 AND 12 (200 XP untill level 21)" doesn't make sense, not in this context.  Don't forget to run it through a spellcheck and whatnot as well.  A little bit of effort goes a very long way here.

Comment: This is just an assumption: The "11 years of service" badge is an upgrade of the "10 years of service" badge, this 10 year badge will probably be worth 500xp, so this 500 xp was already accounted for, so you got actually just 50 extra xp. I think.

Comment: Arperum = thanks man, but I get a whole new 550, it doesent add 50.

Comment: You sure about that?  I have the six years of service badge, and that's worth 300 XP.  I don't have the previous five year's badges, so it seems pretty logical that it would be an upgrade, with attendant XP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Arperum is correct, it's the same way game badges upgrade.  Each is just worth a successive amount, and the value shown is the total of all badges.

Comment: Hit someone in the face, you'll level up.

Comment: Er.. You do know that the "Years of Service" badge gives `50XP x Years since creation` and 550XP is only enough for Level 5? | His Level 10 (1,000 XP) is probably made up of several game badges, his game count badge and the Years of Service Badge.

Answer (score 15):

The *years of service* badge upgrades the same way as game badges.  The value shown is the **total** XP earned across all unlocked levels of the badge combined.

The most recent badge doesn't actually give you 550 XP, that's just your new total with the addition of the new badge.  So whatever the difference between your total for 11 years and 10 years is, that's how much XP you earned from the new badge.

EDIT:  It's 50 XP per level for this particular badge.  So you earned 50 XP, not 550.

Comment: What a grind for exp lol

Comment: Specifically, it's 50 XP per year.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at your [Steam Profile](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/), the reason you did not level up is because you did not meet the requirements to do so.

Also, when your badge upgrades, it **does not add the total onto your current XP again** (as that would just be OP; overpowered). Instead, what it did was add 50XP (the difference) onto your XP count. So 1,038XP + 50XP = 1,088XP, which does not bring you over the next level's threshold of 1,200XP.

---

Your profile level is determined by the **sum of all the badges' XP values**, meaning that you would have more than just that 11 "Years of Service" badge, as the badge itself (550XP) is only enough to bring you to Level 5 (500-599XP).

As [Frank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/202668/yesterday-i-earned-the-11-years-of-service-badge-and-didnt-level-up#comment274200_202668) had said, leveling up your badges only increases its value (ie. from 500XP to 550XP).

Looking at your [profile](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/badges), you only have 1,088XP:

- [11 Years of Service](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/badges/1) (550XP; `50XP x 11`)
- [Steam Summer Adventure - Purple Team](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/badges/20) (100XP)
- [Community Ambassator](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/badges/2) (Level 2; 200XP)
- [Sharp-eyed Stockpiler](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964015738/badges/13) (238XP)

Since your XP count went from 1,038XP (before your YoS badge upgraded) to 1,088XP (after the upgrade) - You haven't reached the next level requirement (1,200XP for Level 11).
The higher your level, it harder it gets to level up as the level requirements increase every 10 levels.

In case, if you had your level calculations wrong:
*Erm. StackExchange doesn't support tables. So I had to format them as code instead.*

```
| Level # | Min. XP | XP Range  | Level-up Cost |
|---------|---------|-----------|---------------|
| 0       | 0       | 0-99      | 100           |
| 1       | 100     | 100-199   | 100           |
| 2       | 200     | 200-299   | 100           |
| 3       | 300     | 300-399   | 100           |
| 4       | 400     | 400-499   | 100           |
| 5       | 500     | 500-599   | 100           |
| 6       | 600     | 600-699   | 100           |
| 7       | 700     | 700-799   | 100           |
| 8       | 800     | 800-899   | 100           |
| 9       | 900     | 900-999   | 100           |
| 10      | 1000    | 1000-1199 | 200           |
| 11      | 1200    | 1200-1399 | 200           |
| 12      | 1400    | 1400-1599 | 200           |
                  and so on...
```

---

As for how to increase them?
**They can be increased by doing the following actions:**

- Crafting and Upgrading existing Badges
- Buying Games
- Earning Badges (participate in events)
- Waiting out a single year